# LinkedList homework problems

Tags: java

Create a program that uses Linked Lists. Your program should
a.  demonstrate both iterative and recursive traversals of linked lists.
b.  demonstrate both iterative and recursive element count of linked lists.
c.  demonstrates recursively adding an element to the end of a linked list.
d.  Tests the code for linked list processing

I've done the first two as shown below

```
public Node returnHead(){
    return head;
}
public void traverseIterative(){
    Node newHead = head;
    while(newHead != null){
        System.out.print(newHead.data + " ");
        newHead = newHead.next;
    }
}
public void traverseRecursive(Node newHead){
    if(newHead == null){
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.print(newHead.data + " ");
        traverseRecursive(newHead.next);
    }
}
public void elementCountIterative(){
    int count = 0;
    Node newHead = head;
    while(newHead != null){
        newHead = newHead.next;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("The size is: " + count);
}
public int elementCountRecursive(Node newHead){
    if(newHead == null){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + elementCountRecursive(newHead.next);
}
}
```

I only added returnHead() because I can't access the head as its private, and I don't know how else to use my recursive methods, but I'm open to ideas. My question is about part c, my code didn't work

```
public void elementAddRecursive(Node newHead, Node addedNode){
        if(newHead == null){
            newHead = addedNode;
        } else {
            elementAddRecursive(newHead.next, addedNode);
        }
    }
```

Here's the driver program

```
public class LinkedListTest {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    LinkedList newList = new LinkedList();
    Node node1 = new Node(50);
    Node node2 = new Node(42);
    Node node3 = new Node(62);
    Node node4 = new Node(100);
    newList.append(node2);
    newList.prepend(node1);
    newList.prepend(node3);
    newList.elementAddRecursive(newList.returnHead(), node4);
    newList.traverseIterative();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather a common question. This is what I found: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/ It shows how to implement it.